# Is ther a way to get 16bit image from opencv videocapture

Tags: opencv, video-capture, 16-bit

If one camera support 16bit gray image, how to get 16bit image via opencv videocapture class?

Can we do this with by cam.set CV2 CAP_PROP_FORMAT properties? 
If yes, how to set this properties?

env:
windows 10

opencv3.1 python binding

python 3.6.3

webcam: purethermal with raw 16bit data feeding

Comment: Mmmm... it might be a good idea to tell us which camera you are referring to, and which Operating System and which versions of everything...

Comment: It's almost always better to use the API that came with the camera with openCV, the videocapture class is really just for simple demos with a webcam.

Answer (score 4):

This code example works for me :

```
import cv2
device_index = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device_index+cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('Y','1','6',' '))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)
code, frame = cap.read()
```

from :

https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3387/~/boson-video-and-image-capture-using-opencv-16-bit-y16/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNTkxNzk5OTQwL2dlbi8xNTkxNzk5OTQwL3NpZC9mVW15VlhkTVpMVE5YcEVvT0dnc20lN0VIN0F6X0ZhV0ZEWjJqT0VtZFgyeDczOWpXV1RvVUNRZXQ3UmdabHJidjVXZDhEaEF1SjVPa2h6OEZOdThVRVNJT2JsclFGenpoNGQ0R2NoZ0xiaGx4TFdFN1czbHdnZzk4USUyMSUyMQ==